# Should I use File.write?

Tags: ruby, documentation

I recently run into problems converting a ruby script to .EXE because I had a `File.write` statement in it. The documentation doesn't mention the `write` method but when I do a

```
pp File.methods
```

it is there. So should I use `File.write`? In a normal Ruby script the following works

```
File.write("test.txt", "test")
```

But is it good practice and why doesn't the documentation mention it?

Comment: What did you use to convert it to EXE? What sort of problem did it have with `File.write`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.write` is in fact `IO.write` (`File` is a child of `IO`) which can be verified by monkey-patching:

```
class IO
  def IO.write
    puts "IO's class method write was called."
  end
end

File.write # outputs "IO's class method write was called."
```

It is very well [in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-write).

Thus, I see no reason not to use it.

Comment: Thnx undur, but i use File.write, not IO.write, please explain

Comment: `File` is a sub-class of `IO`. It inherits all methods from `IO`. If you call `File.write`, the interpreter will not find `write` in `File`, look it up from the super-class `IO`, find it there and call it as shown in my code above. See http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/inheritance.html.